# Using CSS transition on SVG transform scale

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, transform

I am trying to build a zoom option over my SVG. I wanted to use the CSS Transition to do the zoom more smoothly. For some reason it's not working.

```
 <style>
     #bbb {
    -webkit-transition: transform 0.5s;
        -moz-transition: transform 0.5s;
        -o-transition: transform 0.5s;
        transition: transform 0.5s;
     }
 </style>

 <svg version="1.1" id="myimage" baseProfile="full" currentScale="1" width="800" height="600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="border:1px solid black;background-color:black;" viewBox="0 0 800 600">
   <g id="bbb" transform="scale(1) translate(0,0)">
  <rect width="100%" height="100%"  />
  <circle cx="150" cy="100" r="80" fill="green" />
  <text x="150" y="125" font-size="60" text-anchor="middle" fill="white">SVG</text>
  </g>
</svg>

<button onclick="setScale(4);">Test Scale</button>

<script>
   function setScale(scale) {
        document.getElementById('bbb').setAttribute("transform", 'scale(' + scale + ')');
   }
</script>
```

Any ideas how to use CSS Transitions on SVG Transform property ?

(* edited a typo)

Comment: I can get the zoom to work great. But not smoothly as I expect it to be using the transition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

transition comes with CSS rules from style sheets, what you do is to add an attribute.

If you use CSS transition via style sheets, it works fine i believe : **[DEMO TEST via CSS & attribute](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zqafm)**

CSS of demo

```
a:focus + svg #bbb {
  transform:scale(4);
}
#bbb {
  transition:1s;
}
svg {
  vertical-align:top;
}
a:focus {
  pointer-events:none;/* demo purpose*/
}
```

And HTML used for demo purpose .

```
<a tabindex="0"> toggle zoom circle CSS only </a> 
<svg version="1.1"
```

Comment: Thanks GCyrillus and @user3750032. It does work when I change the style. But now for some reason, it's work good on FF but not on Chrome. And it works for scale() but not for translate(,) - Any idea why ?

Comment: @aviv I updated the codepen : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/pLzxc . added prefixfree.js and translate(). to make sure it works , you can set intial values of transform attributes to 0 in CSS.

Comment: GCyrillus, you are you saying this will ONLY work when the transition is through css.  Is there a way to get transitions when modifying the transform programatically?

Comment: @Amber if you update transform value via js, it is still a CSS rule that is applied, if transition is set it should do its job, or do you mean updates via steps through JS via a loop ? (wich is what transition does ... looping via steps from initial value to the new one ;) )

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because `transition` will only transition CSS properties, not SVG specific attributes.

You can set  `transform` as an inline style using the `.style` property though.

```
function setScale(scale) {
    document.getElementById('bbb').style.transform = "scale(" + scale + ")";
}
```

Comment: Of course, you'll have to account for each browsers vendor prefix as well.